# Online Pair Programming with Python

Tags: python, editor, collaboration

I'm working with a team mate solving some programming challenges online

I was wondering if there was something like [piratepad](http://piratepad.net/front-page/) but for python

Ideally it would allow us to collaborate on the same script online, see what the other is editing, chat, and also run it.

Any idea if there's something like that available for python programming? (js would also come handy)

I've found [this](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php) which seems pretty great, but it doesn't seem to support multiple people working on the same code

Answer (score 4):

cloud9 (https://c9.io) seems to work for that, but I never tried.

I know it is an old question but I stumbled uponit.